# gsub! On an argument doesn't work

Tags: ruby

I am making a function that turns the first argument into a PHP var (useless, I know), and set it equal to the second argument. I'm trying to `gsub!` it to get rid of all the characters that can't be used in a PHP var. Here is what I have:

```
dvar = "$" + name.gsub!(/.?\/!@\#{}$%^&*()`~/, "") { |match| puts match }
```

I have the `puts match` there to make sure some of the characters were removed. `name` is a variable passed into a method in which this is its purpose. I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
cVar at ./Web.rb:31
(root) at C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Web\lib\main.rb:13
```

`Web.rb` is the file this line is in, and `main.rb` is the file calling this method. How can I fix this?

EDIT: If I remove the ! in gsub!, it goes through, but the characters aren't removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

Use ``` dvar = "$" + name.tr(".?\/!@\#{}$%^&*()``~", '') ```

### Long answer

The problem you are facing is that the gsub! call is returning nil. You can't concatenate (+) a String with a nil.

That's happening because you have a malformed Regexp. You aren't escaping the special regex symbols, like $, * and ., just for a start. Also, the way it is now, gsub will only match if your string contains all that symbols in sequence. You should use the pipe (|) operator to make an OR like operation.

gsub! will also return nil if no substitutions happened.
 See the documentation for gsub and gsub! here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186
I think you should replace gsub! with gsub. Do you really need `name` to change?

Example:

```
name = "m$var.name$$"
dvar = "$" + name.gsub!(/\$|\.|\*/, "") # $ or . or *
# dvar now contains $mvarname and name is mvarname
```

Your line, corrected:

```
dvar = "$" + name.gsub(/\.|\?|\/|\!|\@|\\|\#|\{|\}|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\`|\~/, "")
# some things shouldn't (or aren't needed to) be escaped, I don't remember them all right now
```

As J-_-L appointed, you could also use a character class ([]), that makes it a little clearer, I guess. Well, it's hard to mentally parse anyway.

```
dvar = "$" + name.gsub(/[\.\?\/\!\@\\\#\{\}\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\`\~]/, "")
```

But because what you are doing is simple character replacement, the best method is tr (again reminded by J-_-L!):

```
dvar = "$" + name.tr(".?\/!@\#{}$%^&*()`~", '')
```

Way easier to read and make modifications.

Comment: By the way, the ultra secret super method to remove single chars is `tr` - just list all chars in the first string: `name.tr(".?\/!@\#{}$%^&*()``~",'')`

Answer (score 3):

i dont see what the block is for
just do

```
name = 'hello.?\/!@#$%^&*()`~hello'
dvar = "$" + name.gsub(/\.|\?|\\|\/|\!|\@|\#|\{|\}|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\`|\~/, "")
puts dvar # => "$hellohello"
```

or use [] to denote OR

```
dvar = "$" + name.gsub(/[\.\?\\\/\!\@\\\#\{\}\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\`\~]/, "")
```

you have to escape the special characters and then OR them so it will remove them individually not just if they are all found together

also there  is really no need to use `gsub!` to modify the string in place use the non mutator `gsub()` since you assign it to a new variable,

`gsub!` returns nil for which the operator + is not defined for stings, which gives you the no method error mentioned

Answer (score 3):

- You cannot apply a second parameter
  **and** a block to gsub (the block is ignored)
- The regex is wrong, you forgot the
  square brackets:
  `/[.?\/!@\#{}$%^&*()`~]/`
- Because your regex is wrong, it
  didn't match anything and because
  gsub! returns nil if nothing was
  replaced, you get this strange nil no
  method error
- btw: you should use gsub not gsub! in
  this case, because you are using the
  return value (and not name itself) --
  and the error would not have happened

Answer (score 2):

It seems as the 'name' object is nil, you may be calling gsub! on nil which usually complains with a NoMethodError: private method gusb! called for nilNilClass, since I don't know the version of ruby you are using I am not sure if the error would be the same, but it's a good place to start looking at.

Comment: it's JRuby 1.6.1. And I also have a type check:                    if name.class != String
        puts "The first var must be a String!"
        exit(1)
end

Comment: name is not nil, but rather name.gsub! is returning nil since there are no substitutions made